# php ini_set() changes don't take with safe mode off

Tags: php, output-buffering, ini-set

I wanted to turn output buffering off. Currently it shows `no value` for local and master. I run `ini_set('output_buffering',4092);` and no changes in `phpinfo()`. Safe mode is off.

What's the next thing to check?

Comment: `output_buffering` is a harmful directive. You always can write a *proper* code that doesn't rely on it. So how about fixing the root of the issue, not pretending there is no any?

Comment: That doesn't in any way address my *question*. I am not asking for best practice. I want to know why it isn't working.

Comment: Are you able to edit the `php.ini`? You might have more luck setting the directive directly.

Comment: @Jared Eitnier: "I am not asking for best practice" --- it's actually very common for newbies to now know how to implement things properly. That's why here on stackoverflow the advices about best practices are preferred over a direct answers to the questions. So, uhm, it's the case when instead of producing another piece of bad code you have a great chance to write something nice.

Comment: @zerkms I understand and this is a constant disagreement between users on this network however if I wanted best practice I would have also asked for that advice. I do appreciate your advice though, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`output_buffering` can only be set via `PHP_INI_PERDIR` which according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) is:

> Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since
>   PHP 5.3)

Only `PHP_INI_ALL` and `PHP_INI_USER` allows setting directive inside a PHP file.

Comment: Well you answered my question & I learned something new. Thanks!